# Why is my image not displaying in my HR?

Tags: html, css, meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I've got this HTML in my Meteor app:

```
<template name='layout'>
  {{> banner}}
  {{> yield}}
</template>

<template name="banner">
  <h1 class="monospaceboldsmallcap chocolatefont">Platypi of the World Unite! (Duckbilled, that is)</h1>
  <hr/>
</template>
```

...and this CSS:

```
hr {
  background:url('/images/dbp.jpg') repeat-x top left;
  border: 0;
}
```

The image is in /public/images/dbp.jpg, yet it does not display at all - in fact, the former "plain jane" hr is no longer displaying, either.

What am I missing or doing wrong here?

Comment: You might need to set a height value.

Comment: You could also try to put one more dot in front of the slash: './images/dbp.jpg'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define height in your `hr` tag.

```css
hr{border:1px solid red;height:30px;background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJ2Se.png?s=32&g=1)}
```

```html
<hr>
```

Comment: That's a weird picture you used;-)

Comment: I thought it will make you feel more connected. :P